# jQuery Tools tooltip problem - jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tooltip, jquery-tools

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$("img").tooltip();
$("a").tooltip();
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="main">
<a href="#">testing</a>
<img src="trollface.jpg" title="Hello, imma trollface!" />
</div>
</div>
```

In the above case, [tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) works only on `<img>` tag.

I haven't added any CSS on `<img>` or `<a>`.

```
$("a").hover(
function() {
    $(this).animate({color: "white"}, 400);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({color: "black"}, 400);
})
```

The above, however, doesn't work now.

Answer (score 1):

By default the tooltip() method will display content contained in the elements "title" attribute.  Since your `<a>` doesn't have a title attribute, the tooltip is not displaying anything.  If you add a title attribute to that tag like this:

```
<a href="#" title="This is my anchor tag">testing</a>
```

It should work.

Comment: Still doesn't work. And I want to load html content within that tooltip.

Comment: If you want to use an HTML tooltip you have to build out div's with a class of "toolip" - which you don't seem to have in your example code. Check out an example at http://jsfiddle.net/s7Fte/.

Comment: I have it, I just didn't specify it. By the way, I tried it in Google Chrome, it worked. I'm using Firefox 5.

Comment: Okay, worked now. There was some problem with .js file I had downloaded I suppose, I edited with the direct link. Thank you.